# how to convert Epanet .inp file to shape file with any thirdparty tools(available in java/C#/javascript)?

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, shapefile, esri

I would like to convert EPANET .inp file into different shape files (for ex single epanet .inp file might contain junctions,reservoirs ,tanks etc..So i need different shape files for same). How do i do it? Is there any third party open source code available? Any kind of help/suggestions would help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to convert MikeUrban networks (eg. shapefiles) to EPANet networks. Did you find a tool for that or do I have to write one myself?

Answer (score 1):

The inp2shp command of the Inptools package converts an EPANET .inp file into separate shapefiles for the different network elements. It's open source (GPL) and cross platform. Have a look at http://epanet.de/inptools/